# How is free disk space on ext4 calculated?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I know there are tools like `df` which show the disk space remaining on disks but I could not find any info on how this tool actually gets this info. I would imagine the filesystem keeps track of this information somehow but I can't find info on this either.

Is there a plain explanation on how this information is gathered from filesystem (specifically ext4) or any terms that would help for finding this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see what `df` does using `strace`:

```
$ strace df / |& grep -i ext
statfs("/", {f_type=EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=4611519, f_bfree=864281, f_bavail=624269, f_files=1179648, f_ffree=620737, f_fsid={126240841, 1491846125}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
```

And from [`man 2 statfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html):

```
The statfs() system call returns information about a mounted
filesystem.  path is the pathname of any file within the mounted
filesystem.  buf is a pointer to a statfs structure defined
approximately as follows:

   struct statfs {
       __fsword_t f_type;    /* Type of filesystem (see below) */
       __fsword_t f_bsize;   /* Optimal transfer block size */
       fsblkcnt_t f_blocks;  /* Total data blocks in filesystem */
       fsblkcnt_t f_bfree;   /* Free blocks in filesystem */
       fsblkcnt_t f_bavail;  /* Free blocks available to
                                unprivileged user */
       fsfilcnt_t f_files;   /* Total file nodes in filesystem */
       fsfilcnt_t f_ffree;   /* Free file nodes in filesystem */
       fsid_t     f_fsid;    /* Filesystem ID */
       __fsword_t f_namelen; /* Maximum length of filenames */
       __fsword_t f_frsize;  /* Fragment size (since Linux 2.6) */
       __fsword_t f_flags;   /* Mount flags of filesystem
                                (since Linux 2.6.36) */
       __fsword_t f_spare[xxx];
                       /* Padding bytes reserved for future use */
   };
```

If you just want the freespace of a mount point, `statfs` seems to be way to go. Free blocks * block size = free space ( - reserved space, etc.).

---

I imagine ext4 must keep [the count of free blocks somewhere in the superblock](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L1183), which you then use with the block size to get the free space.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think it's that element, but I don't know what `lo` stands for, hence the vagueness.

Comment: Maybe a mnemonic  to remember in some part of the code it is a 32 bits value, I suspect. Not sure either.

Comment: Did neither of you notice the corresponding `_hi` members a few lines further down?  And the comment just above those `_hi` members?

Comment: @JdeBP nope. I only looked in the immediate vicinity. So `s_free_blocks_count_hi`*2^32+`s_free_blocks_count_lo` in 64-bit systems?

Comment: [One has to take endianism into account as well, and the fields used to have different names.](http://ftp.dei.uc.pt/pub/linux/kernel/people/tytso/ext4-patches/old/2.6.23-ext4-1/broken-out/ext4-convert_s_r_blocks_count_and_s_free_blocks_count.patch)  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Even after you talking about them, I was not finding them, had to use the search function. I was telling initially to muru it would be part of the low value of a 64-bit number, but then did not find the the higher part and deleted the comment... dummy.

Comment: I think I'll stick with the vague sentence with the link to that element and let OP figure out the details. :D